# Unity How to set local space in rigitbody MovePosition?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a code for moving an object through Rigitbody, but there is a problem, unlike Transform.Translate, there is no local space parameter in Rigitbody, that is, the object will move not towards the camera, but towards global coordinates. How can I change global coordinates to local?

`

```
Vector3 m_imput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0, -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        _rb.MovePosition(transform.position + m_imput * Time.deltaTime * move_speed);
```

`

How to set local coordinate system in Rigitbody?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html

Comment: Apart from @WillardPeng comment, Rigidbody also has `AddRelativeForce()` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try using transform.forward and transform.right:

```
inputVert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
inputHorz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + inputVert * speed * Time.deltaTime * transform.forward);
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + inputHorz * speed * Time.deltaTime * transform.right);
```